# Assembly build number incorrect, and revision doesn't change in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, assemblyversionattribute

There is a project, we specify the Assembly version number as 1.1.*, which to my understanding, means that the third number (build number) and the fourth number(revision number) will be auto-generated and the rule is the the build number will be the number of days since 1.1.2000, and revision number will be seconds since midnight divided by two. However, after I build this project today, 31.7.2012, the build number is 4590, which corresponds to the date 26.7.2012 (even though in Windows explorer it says this file is modified at 31.7.2012 !), and the revision number is always 27021, no matter what time I build it today.

I was wondering, is there some other parameters that control the auto-versioning that could produce such result? Thanks!